# How to pass a variable to chrome.tab.create?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I pass a variable to chrome.tabs.create?

I'm trying to set up event listeners to my anchors, but I'm creating them inside a for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    if(links[i][0] === text){
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.setAttribute('href', links[i][2]);
        a.setAttribute('class','links_anchor');
        a.innerHTML = links[i][1];
        
        test = links[i][2];
        a.addEventListener('click', function(){
            chrome.tabs.create({
                url: test,
                active: false
            });
        });

        document.getElementById('links_content').appendChild(a);
    }
}
```

How can I pass a variable to the url parameter? What's happening now is that all the links have the same action. E.g. When I click any of them it opens the last URL from the array.

Comment: You can probably get away  with `url: this.href` instead of `url: test`. `this` refers to element the handler is bound to, thus you are avoiding the whole closure problem.

Comment: perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean add a query parameter like so:
https://example.com/?foo=bar

Seeing as you have the url in test you could turn
chrome.tabs.create({
url: test,
active: false
});

into

chrome.tabs.create({
url: test + "?foo=bar&bar=foo"
active: false
});